# How to move cursor after a specific word in email body

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I wrote this code to move Outlook cursor 5 words to right:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection
Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor
    Set Selection = wdDoc.Application.Selection
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=5, Extend:=wdMove
Set Inspector = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set Selection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Do you have any idea how to move mouse cursor after a specific word in email body?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Work with [Find.Execute method MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute) Find the word then move the cursor*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection

    Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor
    Set Selection = wdDoc.Application.Selection

    With Selection.Find
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Text = "word"
        .Execute
    End With

    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove

End Sub
```

> [image]